# Oops while traversing sk_write_queue in Linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, oop, tcp, kernel

My Linux 3.8.8 kernel would Oops while traversing tcp sk_write_queue in kernel, like below:

```
BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at 00b85055
```

My code logic in kernel is as below:

1. Get struct socket from socket file descriptor;
2. Get struct sock from struct socket;
3. lock_sock();
4. Get sk_write_queue from struct sock;
5. traverse sk_write_queue, read linked skb buffer;
6. release_sock();
7. return to user space.

While in step (5), sometimes will trigger Oops above, the problem code is:

```
skb_is_nonlinear(skb);
```

It means that skb pointer now is invalid or null, can't the lock_sock protect the traverse process?

Code:

```
asmlinkage long sys_tcp_get(int fd, int *id)
{
    int err, i, j;
    struct socket *sock;
    struct sock *sk;
    struct sk_buff_head *queue;
    struct sk_buff *skb;
    unsigned char buf[4] = {0};

    sock = sockfd_lookup(fd, &err);
    if (sock == NULL) return -1;

    sk = sock->sk;
    if (sk == NULL) {
            err = -1;
            goto free_socket;
    }

    lock_sock(sk);

    if (((1 << sk->sk_state) & ~TCPF_ESTABLISHED) ||
            (sk->sk_err || (sk->sk_shutdown & SEND_SHUTDOWN))) {
                    err = -1;
                    goto release_socket;
    }

    queue = &(sk->sk_write_queue);
    if (tcp_send_head(sk) == NULL) {
            err = -1;
            goto release_socket;
    }

    for(skb = tcp_send_head(sk); skb != (struct sk_buff *)(queue); skb = skb->next) {
            if (skb_is_nonlinear(skb)) {
                    err = -1;
                    goto release_socket;
            }

            i = 0;
            j = 0;
            while(i < skb->len) {
                    buf[j++] = skb->data[i++];
                    if (j == 4) {
                            if (buf[0] == 1 && buf[1] == 2 && buf[2] == 3) {
                                   *id = buf[3];
                                    err = 0;
                                    goto release_socket;
                            } else {
                                    j = 0;
                            }
                    }
            }
    }

release_socket:
    release_sock(sk);

free_socket:
    sockfd_put(sock);
    return err;
}
```

Comment: Could you post your code here? The details in it might be significant.

Comment: I've list the code above, problem happens with skb_is_nonlinear function.